# how to make attributed text field without entering the text in text field?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a text field which has a image as background.Due to that image text is starting from most left corner & there is not even 1px space between text & edge of textfield.I want to give some spacing between them.I have tried making text field attributed but for that i have to enter some text.How can i make text attributed without entering text into textfield ?

Comment: You can set a kind of offset to `UITextField` (there are some question on SO about it), but it seems that you should show how you put your image in your `UITextField` too.

Comment: Why don't you simply make this image the `leftView` of the textField? However, as @Larme said, can't really help unless we know what you have tried. Please share some code.